# Warn user before leaving Website with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a code that warns/alerts the user if they want to stay on or leave the Website when they click on a link that goes to another Website. I tried [this](http://dev.codepotato.co.uk/create-warning-opening-external-links-jquery/) and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
  return "Bye now!";
});
```

more here https://api.jquery.com/unload/

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmExit;
```

`function ConfirmExit()
{
    return "closed....";
}`

Comment: this is not jquery implementation

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'on before unload' event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = onbeforeunload_handler;
    window.onunload = onunload_handler;
    function onbeforeunload_handler() {
        // Do something here
    }

    function onunload_handler() {
       // Or do something here
    }
</script>
```